# NSPrintOperation—save to location without prompt

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, pdf-generation, swift3

I have a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/owlswipe/CocoaPDFCreator) that allows the user to save a paginated PDF on Mac from some HTML by loading it into a WebView and using an `NSPrintOperation` (specifically, an `NSPrintSaveJob` with `showsPrintPanel` set to false) lets the user save that PDF to any location on their Mac with a [save panel](http://images.cnitblog.com/i/625506/201404/241548371547305.png) similar to the default `NSSavePanel`. However, I'm experimenting with the code and I'd like to instead save the created PDF to a particular folder (`/Users/owlswipe/Downloads/`) without the save panel.

My code to save a PDF from a WebView (with a save panel) is currently this:

```
let printOpts: [String : AnyObject] = [NSPrintJobDisposition:NSPrintSaveJob as AnyObject]
let printInfo: NSPrintInfo = NSPrintInfo(dictionary: printOpts)
printInfo.paperSize = NSMakeSize(595.22, 841.85)
let printOp: NSPrintOperation = NSPrintOperation(view: webView.mainFrame.frameView.documentView, printInfo: printInfo)
printOp.showsPrintPanel = false
printOp.showsProgressPanel = false
printOp.run()
```

How can I adapt that code to save the PDF to a preset folder instead of to the user's choice of folders from a save panel?

Comment: `NSPrintOperation` also has a class method `func pdfOperation(with: NSView, inside: NSRect, toPath: String, printInfo: NSPrintInfo)`.

Answer (score 2):

This piece of code is working for me in Swift 4/Cocoa to accomplish what you want, however there's a bit more code in there as it is rendering the contents of a WKWebView into 8.5" x 11" pages for a PDF.

So for your app, there would be appropriate adjustments for your content stream / print object, but the configuration of the print operation will be the same to get the "no dialog" results you're wanting.

However, to test it out you could just dump your string into the webview and use the code as is.  Generated files appear in the root of your "user/documents" directory.

```
static func createPDF(htmlString: String, streamId: String = "someStream") {

    let webView = WebView()
    webView.mainFrame.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + 1

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {

       let directoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
       let directoryURLStr = directoryURL.absoluteString+"\(streamId).pdf"

       let outputFilePath = URL(string: directoryURLStr)

       let printOpts: [NSPrintInfo.AttributeKey : Any] = [
         NSPrintInfo.AttributeKey.jobDisposition : NSPrintInfo.JobDisposition.save,
         NSPrintInfo.AttributeKey.jobSavingURL   : outputFilePath
       ]

       let printInfo: NSPrintInfo = NSPrintInfo(dictionary: printOpts)
       let baseMargin: CGFloat    = 9.0; // .125"

       printInfo.paperSize    = NSMakeSize(612, 792); // 8.5" x 11/2"
       printInfo.topMargin    = baseMargin
       printInfo.leftMargin   = baseMargin
       printInfo.rightMargin  = baseMargin
       printInfo.bottomMargin = baseMargin

       let printOp: NSPrintOperation = NSPrintOperation(view: webView.mainFrame.frameView.documentView, printInfo: printInfo)

       printOp.showsPrintPanel = false
       printOp.showsProgressPanel = false
       printOp.run()

       Swift.print("Document complete: \(outputFilePath!.absoluteString)")
   }
 }
```